# Calling a stored procedure in SQL Server to get a unicode string

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc

I'm trying to get a name by calling a stored procedure.

sql code:

```
create procedure GetName
@ID int,
@name nvarchar(32) output
as
select @name=name from SalesInfo where ID=@ID
```

c code

```
...
SQLRETURN rc;
SQLLEN cbParam = SQL_NTS;
int ID = 1;
wchar_t name[32];

rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_SLONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &ID, 0, NULL);
rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, SQL_C_WCHAR, SQL_WCHAR, SQL_DESC_LENGTH, 0, name, sizeof(name), &cbParam);
rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, TEXT("{call GetName(?,?)}"), SQL_NTS);
```

1. I received a string, but there was an error message, 'string data, right truncation'
2. The string was padded with blanks, like "name       "

Comment: you need to increase the size of your nvarchar() so that it doesnt pad the strings that are larger than 32

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase the size of your nvarchar() so that it doesn't truncate the strings that are larger than 32

increase the size of `wchar_t name[N];`and `@name nvarchar(N) output`

Answer (score 0):

Well to get rid of the trim simply use RTRIM(col) AS [col], to determin what length of char vars you need then LEN(Originalcol) or DATALENGTH(Originalcol) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx in your case to create a proc to see waht actual length you are getting and what you need to define. As its a single var, you wont get much a hit by using NVARCHAR(MAX)